# Unable to show column names in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I created small form in Java in which used `JTable` and to fill the table. I used the following code.

```
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

 try
 {
        CreateConnection();
        PreparedStatement st =conn.prepareStatement("Select * from ABC;");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
        jtable_clock.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        conn.close();
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {    
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
 }
```

Here everything works fine but I am unable to set Column Names in my table.

I am getting data from table ABC but how can I set Column Names in table?

Comment: 1- Did you add the table to a `JScrollPane`? 2- Where did you get `DbUtils`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes my Jtable is already inside Jscrollpane.

Comment: Show your code of DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs).

Comment: @MasudCSECUET actuall there is jar file rs2xml which i used to know the code of that jar file here is the link. http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/59-resultset-to-tablemodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not got any problem. Try to run my code. Replace my DB username & password.

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

/**
 *
 * @author Masud
 */
public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() throws HeadlessException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zoodb", "root", "12345678");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from ABC");
            JTable jTable = new JTable(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(resultSet));
            JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(jTable);
            add(pane);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Test();
    }
}
```